# routeProvider not loading new views

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I have my config as follows:

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});

$routeProvider.when('/:schema/home',{
    templateUrl:'/views/homeView',
    controller:'homeController',
    reloadOnSearch:true
}).when('/:schema/details',{
    templateUrl:'/views/detailsView',
    controller:'detailsController',
    reloadOnSearch:true
}).otherwise({
     redirectTo:'/potato'
});

}]);
```

in my home view i have a table where the first cell in each row should redirect the user to the /details page.

```
                    <tr ng-repeat="p in ps">
                    <td><a ng-href="/{{model.getSchema()}}/details" >{{p.name}}</a></td></tr>
```

in the view when i hover over the link, it previews exactly what i expect it to.

My problem is when i click the link(s) it changes the URL, but the view does not change. I am not sure of the underlying issue at all.

Comment: Make sure you aren't getting a 404 error for the views.  Check the network log in the developer console

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond , when i type the url (/schema/details) into browser it works with no 404

Comment: But make sure it isn't trying to do a request to a relative url just in case.  Check the developer console it should give you a better idea what is wrong

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond in chrome when i hover over the link it gives me the full path it tries to take me, and it is correct. am i looking for something else?

Comment: If you press F12 it will tell you specifically the full path of the requested item, it is just to test to make sure the request is 100% correct. Angular sometimes may not request exactly what you think your url is, and in this case would request the view file as an absolute path if I am not mistaken